# Java EE Future NullPointer

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm new to `java.util.concurrent` package and i came to a problem with `Future` object.

This is a conversationScoped bean.

```
@Inject SomeBean stateFull;

Boolean comp = false, comp1 = false;

public void doSomething(){        

    stateFull.runProcess();   

    try {

        comp = stateFull.getFuture().get();    
        System.out.println("Future "+syncEJB.getFuture().get());
        updateView();

        comp1 = stateFull.getFuture1().get();   
        System.out.println("Future "+syncEJB.getFuture().get());
        updateView();

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SynchronizationMB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SynchronizationMB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```

SomeBean looks like this.

```
@Stateful
public class SomeBean{    

    @Inject AnotherBean stateLess;

    private volatile Future<Boolean> future, future1;

    @Asynchronous
    public void runProcess(){
        future = stateLess.compute(); 
        future1 = stateLess.compute(); 

    }
    public Future<Boolean> getFuture() {
        return future;
    }
    public Future<Boolean> getFuture1() {
        return future1;
    }
}
```

And AnotherBean:

```
@Stateless
public class AnotherBean{

@Asynchronous
public Future<Boolean> compute() {
    boolean result;


    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("completed sync");
    System.out.println("--------------");

    result = true;

    return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(result);
}
}
```

And now to my problem. I call `doSomething()` method and i think that according to documentation of `Future.get()` it should call `runProcess()` and than wait at
`comp = stateFull.getFuture().get();`
until future in SomeBean is completed from AnotherBean, but it just keep throwing `NullPointerException`. Anyone knows why it can be be happening?

-------------------EDIT-----------------------

NullPointer has been corrected. Now i have another problem. Let's say that i set more Future objects in Somebean by calling more methods in runProcess(). And then i want to update my page everytime the Future object get a result to see the progress. How do i do that? Right now i use

```
private void updateView(){
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ctx.update("mainFrm:info");
}
```

under every Boolean in doSomething() method, but it doesnt do what i want. All booleans just appear all at once.

Comment: Why aren't you simply defining: `public Future<Boolean> runProcess(){ return stateLess.compute(); }`, what's the purpose of this extra variable?

Comment: because i will be calling more of similar methods in runProcess() right now theres only one for testing purpose, same with that boolean in conversationScoped bean, there will be more

Comment: first find which value is null, looking at the stack trace: is at stateFull.runProcess() or at stateFull.getFuture().get()?

Comment: it is selected in code where nullpointer occures, at stateFull.getFuture().get()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPE happens because starting new thread is a heavy operation, and when you call `stateFull.getFuture().get();` new thread is not started yet(so feature is null).

[Here](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/08/spring-asynchronous-support/) the right way of using `@Async` with Future.

Comment: nice idea but looks like not source of problem. I tryed to set Thread object like this `thisThread = Thread.currentThread();` in SomeBean of this Asynchronous call and than check in while cycle till its alive in conversationScoped bean but nullPointer remains

Comment: `future` filed must be at least `volatile` - because it updated and obtained in different threads.

Comment: ok so now it stopped throwing NPE but IllegalStateException started. `Object does not represent an acutal Future`

Comment: great thanks you very much. The last exception was cause by me using get() with timeout attribute :)